# finding text using contains

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

This may seem like a simple questiom, but I have the following html

```
 <div class="price">£4.99</div>
```

I'd like to add the word `From` to the beginning of this using jQuery.

I have the following:

```
$('.price:contains("£4.99")').html("(From: &#163;4.99)");
```

This doesn't seem to do anything.

The source has a `�`, which I'm guessing is to do with the pound sign.

Am I doing this right?

Thanks

UPDATE:
This HTML is in a PHP script.

Comment: It's working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DtqT3/).

Comment: Have you checked the character encoding in your editor, and html? No-repro, as with Sheikh Heera, for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this:

```
$(".price:contains(\xA34.99)").html("From \xA34.99")
```

Comment: +1. it worked because I think in your `html` you have `&#163;` instead of `£`.

Answer (score 0):

Even `text` would do your job

```
$('.price:contains("£4.99")').text('From: £4.99');
```

Comment: `val()` is entirely inappropriate as there is no `value` attribute in a `div` element. `text()` would work, though.

Answer (score 0):

Before adding the word `From`, try this:

```
alert($('.price:contains("£4.99")').html());
```

What does it print?  If the alert does prints nothing, it means the selector isn't working for some reason.